# Push to Second View Controller with mapkit info button

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

Once a Pin is selected is selected in my app, I want the info button to link to the below view controller.

[image: 2nd View Controller]

I would know how to do this if the button was on the screen from the start, but it is not present until a pin is selected. How Can I implement this? my button is currently simply coded as the following:

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        print("Button tapped ")
    }
}
```

Also, If this is Segue would I be able to have this one view controller and have the text and photos change depending on which info pin button is clicked on?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your annotation has a title your map view will respond to selecting the annotation through the delegate method

```
optional func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)
```

This method will be called by the map view when you select your annotation. You can implement this method in the view controller that you have designated as the delegate of the map view and tell your map view delegate what to do, including perform segue. This means that you have your viewcontroller initiated, like:

```
class myMapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
// Your class code starts here

}
```

Then somewhere in your viewDidLoad() you declare that the delegate of your map view is this view controller by:

```
self.myMapView.delegate = self
```

So, in the delegate you can program your preparations before calling perform segue and then in prepare for segue you prepare the destination view controller for its actions on the annotation being selected.

Just note, the delegate method gives you the annotation view you selected. The annotation that goes with this annotation view is obtained with:

```
let theAnnotation = view.annotation
```

in this delegate method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response, but it has slightly confused me. Would my delegate method be located in the View Controller then along with the  function that dictates what the button does? I am just confused as to what exactly I am supposed to change. Sorry if this is aggravating but I am very new to swift and don't completely understand. If you could help out anymore that would be great.